# str_detect is missing out some samples

Tags: r

I am trying to filter out males and females in my dataset.
I am filtering the Karyotype column; first by Y to extract the male samples.

```
df <- data.frame (sample_ID  = 1:7,
              Karyotype = c("46, XX", "46, XY","UNKNOWN", "PENDING", "47, XY", "45, X", "FAILED")
```

)

```
males <- samples %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Karyotype, "Y"))
```

For the females, I have tried:

```
females <- samples %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(Karyotype, "Y"))
```

But this includes other samples including `"UNKNOWN"` and `"PENDING"`

So I then tried filtering these samples with str_detect for samples including X

```
females <- females %>%
  filter(str_detect(Karyotype, "X"))
```

This works with the dataframe in this example, but when applied to the original file, it misses out "45, X"

```
df <- data.frame (
  sample_ID = 1:7, 
  karyotype = c("46, XX", "46, XY","UNKNOWN", "PENDING", "47, XY", "45, X", "FAILED")) 

males <- df %>% filter(str_detect(karyotype, "Y")) 
females <- df %>% filter(!str_detect(karyotype, "Y")) 
females <- females %>% filter(str_detect(karyotype, "X"))
```

Output: `45, X 46, XX 46, XY 47, XY FAILED PENDING UNKNOWN 1 1 0 0 0 0 0`

So it works when I make my own little dataframe but it doesnt work when using the orginal large file.

Comment: df <- data.frame (sample_ID  = 1:7,
                  karyotype = c("46, XX", "46, XY","UNKNOWN", "PENDING", "47, XY",
                                "45, X", "FAILED"))
males <- df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(karyotype, "Y"))

females <- df %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(karyotype, "Y"))

females <- females %>%
  filter(str_detect(karyotype, "X"))

Output: 
  45, X  46, XX  46, XY  47, XY  FAILED PENDING UNKNOWN 
      1       1       0       0       0       0       0 

So it works when i make my own little dataframe but it doesnt work when using the orginal large file.

Comment: `df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Karyotype, "X"))` works fine: `sample_ID karyotype
1         1    46, XX
2         2    46, XY
3         5    47, XY
4         6     45, X`

Comment: Can you post a part of your actual dataframe with `dput()`?

Answer (score 0):

While you could use `str_detect` to filter your sample, you might want to consider explicitly defining different phenotypes based on chromosomal abnormalities. This may allow for more flexibility and generalizability, including identification of syndromes (Turner's or Klinefelter's). This would address situations when you may have Y only which could be labeled "NONVIABLE" instead of "MALE".

For example, you can separate your `karyotype` result into number chromosomes and sex chromosomes. Then, use logic to define the phenotype. In this case, to simplify, just the sex chromosomes are used to define male and female.

Afterwards, you can `filter` using this new column for further manipulation.

I recognize this may be more than what you need and/or may not apply to the data you have. However, I thought this might be helpful to others doing similar work.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(karyotype, into = c("n_chrom", "sex_chrom"), sep = ", ", fill = "right") %>%
  mutate(sex_chrom = coalesce(sex_chrom, n_chrom),
         sex_pheno = case_when(
           sex_chrom %in% c("XY", "XXY", "XYY") ~ "MALE",
           sex_chrom %in% c("X", "XX", "XXX") ~ "FEMALE",
           TRUE ~ NA_character_
         ))
```

**Output**

```
  sample_ID n_chrom sex_chrom sex_pheno
1         1      46        XX    FEMALE
2         2      46        XY      MALE
3         3 UNKNOWN   UNKNOWN      <NA>
4         4 PENDING   PENDING      <NA>
5         5      47        XY      MALE
6         6      45         X    FEMALE
7         7  FAILED    FAILED      <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_detect` to create the 'sex_pheno'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(sex_pheno = case_when(str_detect(Karyotype, '(X|XX)\\b')
     ~ 'FEMALE', str_detect(Karyotype, 'XY')~ 'MALE'))
```

-output

```
#   sample_ID Karyotype sex_pheno
#1         1    46, XX    FEMALE
#2         2    46, XY      MALE
#3         3   UNKNOWN      <NA>
#4         4   PENDING      <NA>
#5         5    47, XY      MALE
#6         6     45, X    FEMALE
#7         7    FAILED      <NA>
```